# Why changes in Numpy array are not reflecting in two different cases?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am confused about below two codes:

1st code: Changes getting reflected in both array

```
    import numpy as nm

    ab=nm.arange(10)
    ba=ab
    ba[0]=99
    print(ba)
    print (ab)
```

Output:

```
ba=[99  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]

ab=[99  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
```

2nd code: Changes NOT getting reflected in both array

```
    import numpy as nm

    ab=nm.arange(10)
    ba=ab
    ba=ab-ab
    print(ba)
    print(ab)
```

Output:

```
ba=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

ab=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Can anybody please explain this? I want to understand why is it happening? I can see new address is allocated in 2nd case but why is not overwriting the data like in 1st case?

Comment: Your initial `ba=nm.array([])` does nothing for you.  You don't need to preallocate or define variables in Python.  `ba = ab` just assigns the `ab` array object to `ba` as well.  There's no copying.

Comment: I want to understand why is it happening? I can see new address is allocated in 2nd case but why?

Comment: `ab-ab` is making a new array, which is then assigned to `ba`; the previous link between `ba` and `ab` is broken.  In the first case `ba[0]=99` modifies the array that both `ba` and `ab` reference.

Comment: Yea thanks, I got it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable that holds the array actually holds the memory address where the array is located, by doing `ba=ab` you're setting the same address for both arrays, so if you change one of them the changes will be reflected in the other, but by doing `ba=ab-ab` you're overwriting this address with the result of an **evaluation**, and as it is new data it has to be stored in a new memory address.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Numpy and have just started to learn so pardon my ignorance and if you could please provide a detailed answer for why its happening?. I can see that a new address is assiged in second case, but why? Why is it not overwriting the same address with new values as in first case?

Comment: Whenever you overwrite the variable (this is, doing `ba=...`) you will overwrite the address as that is what the variable is holding. It is different if you do `ba[0]=...`, because then you're only altering the values that the array hold.You're probably after something like `ba[:]=ab-ab`, which is telling numpy to change all the values of the array for the result of the evaluation.

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you so much, I see how I was trying to change the address. Thanks again!

Comment: Useful to note this is a common source of bugs even among more experienced NumPy users; e.g. `x -= y` and `x = x-y` are not the same, since the former changes `x` in-place at the current memory address and the latter makes a new array equal to `x-y` and assigns `x` to it.